# Android AdMob overlapping GLSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, admob

I want simply to display a AdMob banner on the bottom side in portrait orientation under a GLSurfaceView.
But it does not work.

Why the AdMob banner is overlapping the GLSurfaceView ?
And why I can only see the AdMob banner if I pause and resume the app after creation once?
I don't like to use a XML layout only for this 2 views so I search for a simple solution completely in code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
    adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("356613124234016")
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(request);

    gameView = new GameView(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.addView(gameView);
    layout.addView(adView, lp);

    setContentView(layout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a solution,
everyone who needs a quick and simple solution:
Here how I solved it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
    adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("356613124234016")
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(request);

    gameView = new GameView(this);


    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams gameP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
    gameP.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams adP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.0f);
    adP.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

    layout.addView(gameView, gameP);
    layout.addView(adView, adP);

    setContentView(layout);
}
```